# Swift accessing inner key and value from dictionary of [String:[String:Any]]

Tags: swift

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
var Dict: [String:[String:Any]] = [:]
```

I know I can access the outter keys by doing:

```
var keys = Array(Dict.keys)
```

But I would like to know how can I access the inner keys and values?

Comment: Consider to use custom structs/classes. They make life so much easier. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mapValue

```
let innerKeys = Dict.mapValues({$0.keys}).values
let innerValues = Dict.mapValues({$0.values}).values
```

Another way if you want to access them in a loop

```
Dict.forEach( {
    //$0 is the outer key
    print($1.keys) //inner keys
    print($1.values) //inner values
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map your dictionary values and initialise a new array from the keys or values:

```
let dict: [String:[String:Any]] = ["a":["key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"]]


let keys = Array(dict.values.map{Array($0.keys)}.joined())
let values = Array(dict.values.map{Array($0.values)}.joined())

print(keys)  // ["key1", "key2"]
print(values)  // ["value1", "value2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code to get all inner keys and values

```
var popularDestArr = [String:[String : Any]]()
popularDestArr = [
        "1abc":["image":"best_of_ott_001", "title":"dubaiHotelsStr","subtitle":"(243 Hotels)"],
        "2def":["image":"best_of_ott_002", "title":"parisHotelsStr","subtitle":"(434 Hotels)"],
        "3ghi":["image":"best_of_ott_003", "title":"istanbulHotelsStr","subtitle":"(151 Hotels)"]
    ]
    //print((popularDestArr as NSDictionary).allKeys)
    //print(((popularDestArr as NSDictionary).allValues[0]) as! NSDictionary)


    for arr in  popularDestArr{
        let dict: [String : Any] = arr.value
        //print(dict)
        for (key,value) in dict{
            print(key)
            print(value)
        }
    }
```